# Numbers in brackets next to the "C" in a complex contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

What does it mean when a contour integral has a pair of numbers in parantheses next to the C at the bottom of the integral sign? A number of my homework problems have this notation but I can't find it explained anywhere!
The chosen function is arbitrary by the way.

$$\int_{C(1,2)} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{2}} \; dz$$

Comment: @Max: I'm guessing he means $C(1,2)$, circle centered at $1$ with radius $2$.

Comment: @notaclue: Is it "$C(1,2)$" or "$\mathbb C(1,2)$"?

Comment: @MPW, it is the first option.

Comment: My bad, @Max, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really mean $C(1,2)$, that's probably the circle with center $1$ and radius $2$.